# Arrays using commander

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, command-line-interface

Hei guys!

I need help with the [commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js) node.js library. I need create this CLI which accepts 3 flags, --input, --output and --pattern, like:

```
commander
  .version('3.0.0')
  .usage('[options] <file ...>')
  .option('-i, --input', 'Array of files to be extracted')
  .option('-o, --output', 'Output file name')
  .option('-p, --pattern', 'Pattern name to be used in the extraction')
  .parse(process.argv);
```

My problem is with the input flag. I need send several files, for that i need an array data type.

The problem is: I just can't figure it out how to make this:

```
node ./bin/extract -i ../files/*.PDF
```

become an array with all my files that are inside my files directory. I already try to run every sample in the documentation, and i didn't find the solution for my problem. Also, i searched in the issues and didn't find either... what is strange, maybe i am doing something wrong and you guys could help??

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**Coercion**](https://github.com/tj/commander.js#coercion)  to achieve it:

```
function scanDir(val) {
    files = fs.readdirSync(val);
    return files;
}

program
    .version('0.0.1')
    .option('-s, --scan [value]', '', scanDir)
    .parse(process.argv);

console.log(' scan: %j', program.scan);
```

And call it like:

```
node app.js -s /foo
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what coercion means in this context?

Comment: It is a way to forcibly modify an option